# iText - built-in event handler when adding elements to a document?

Tags: java, event-handling, itext

I am using iText 4.2 and I desire to construct a bookmark outline for a new document.  I don't want to pollute my code with the bookmarking logic if I can help it.  In iText, I am seeking an interface or base class I can use to handle events such as document.add(), so I can construct my bookmarks as I am adding elements to the document.  Looking online and in Bruno's book, I don't see anything built-in.  Am I wrong?

Comment: Just FYI: iText 4.2.0 was never released by iText Software and will never be endorsed or supported. You don't know what's inside and you should really contact the person who put it online. I believe that's ymasory. Contact them. You use their unofficial version.

Comment: Ymasory's 4.2.0 is the best known one but *anyone* could have created a 4.2.0 built. *If you don't know the source* of your 4.2.0, the danger @Amedee is warning about is even more imminent.

Comment: That been said iText provides events concerning its *processing* what is given to it but not concerning its mere inputs. If you need to be informed about what is added to the `Document`, simply extend the class accordingly.

Comment: Good information.  I will pass it along to my architect.  As for the my question, I will just roll my own event handler.